# Puppet - Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Tags: automation, debian, puppet

when I try to connect the puppet agent with `puppet agent --test`, I have this error :

`Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER :Could not find class <my_module> for <my_agent> on node <my_agent>
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run`

I have `import nodes` on *sites.pp* and `include <my_module>` on *nodes.pp*

***--edit--***

Content of `sites.pp` :

`import "nodes"
filebucket { main: server => "<my_master>" }
File { backup => main }
Exec { path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbon:/bin:/sbin" }`

Content of `nodes.pp` :

`node "<my_agent>" {
    include <my_module>
}`

***--edit--***

What is the real problem ?

Thanks

Comment: show the content of nodes.pp and site.pp

Comment: I have added the content of `nodes.pp` and `sites.pp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another VM, and that's working now ! =)

Maybe I have taken a mistake in the network configuration.